# Strage DNS behavior in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: linux, google-chrome, dns, chromium, archlinux

When I try to visit http://www.taobao.com/ in Chrome I get taken to an ISP error page (http://hndnserror4.wo.com.cn:8080/issueunziped/hn20150626/index.htm?sf=&UserUrl=www.taobao.com). This doesn't happen in Firefox. I've trying clearing the DNS cache both system-wide and in Chrome.

How I can diagnose the issue?

Edit: I've simplified the question for the bounty. This problem happens on Arch Linux. I've tried using [DNSCrypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DNSCrypt). I've changed `/etc/resolv.conf` to use various DNS servers such as Google's. I've tried clearing the host cache from chrome://net-internals/#dns. I've disabled using a web service to help resolve navigation errors in Chrome's settings. Nothing works and every time I try to open taobao.com in Chrome I get the ISP error page. It opens the error page instantly without a redirect or waiting for the hostname to resolve. When I enter "taobao.com" into the address bar and hit enter with the Network tab open I see the first request is recorded as having a request URL of http://hndnserror4.wo.com.cn:8080/issueunziped/hn20150626/index.htm?sf=&UserUrl=www.taobao.com. How is "taobao.com" getting transformed into that between hitting enter and the page loading?

I've submitted a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510680&thanks=510680&ts=1437020912

Comment: doing some looking for those addresses, this might point you the right way: http://superuser.com/questions/796313/ie-dns-lookup-hijacked-by-baidu

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux. I'll try deleting all cached and temporary files.

Comment: Have you checked installed extensions? Anything suspicious there?

Comment: As I mentioned in the bug report I tried a clean profile. That didn't work but clearing the browsing history did. I do think it's a bug because something was being cached that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by clearing the browser data. Strange, but it worked. I went to Settings -> History -> Clear browsing data. With the defaults checked (clear following items from the past hour) it allowed me to visit http://taobao.com again. Creating a new profile didn't help. Nor did clearing the DNS cache from chrome://net-internals. I don't know if it's a bug in Chromium but I'm content to have resolved the issue.